# Modeling class relationships in OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology

I have an ontology which represents my view of occupations and educational degrees.  The model is visually represented like this:

[image: datamodel]

As part of my ontology, I would like to model degree to occupation "pathways" for each degree (as noted in the diagram above).  Here are a couple of examples of what I'm trying to describe:

- if I earn a Bachelor's Degree in Computer Science, I can become any type of Software Developer (including Web Developer, which is a subclass of Software Developer).
- if I earn a Nursing Degree, I can become any type of Nurse, but not a Nurse Manager.

Here is my ontology so far:

```
@prefix : <http://www.test.org/jobs#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.test.org/jobs> .

<http://www.test.org/jobs> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

:hasEducationLevel rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                   rdfs:domain :Degree ;
                   rdfs:range :EducationLevel .

:hasOccupation rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
               rdfs:domain :Job ;
               rdfs:range :Occupation .

:programOfStudy rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                rdfs:domain :Degree ;
                rdfs:range :ProgramOfStudy .

:requiresEducation rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                   rdfs:domain :Job ;
                   rdfs:range :Degree .

:title rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
       rdfs:domain :Job ;
       rdfs:range xsd:string .

:Accounting rdf:type owl:Class ;
            rdfs:subClassOf :Finance .

:Audit rdf:type owl:Class ;
       rdfs:subClassOf :Finance .

:BachelorsDegree rdf:type owl:Class ;
                 owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Degree
                                                            [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                              owl:onProperty :hasEducationLevel ;
                                                              owl:hasValue :BachelorsEducationLevel
                                                            ]
                                                          ) ;
                                       rdf:type owl:Class
                                     ] .

:Computer_Science rdf:type owl:Class ;
                  rdfs:subClassOf :ProgramOfStudy .

:Degree rdf:type owl:Class .

:EducationLevel rdf:type owl:Class .

:Finance rdf:type owl:Class ;
         rdfs:subClassOf :ProgramOfStudy .

:Job rdf:type owl:Class .

:Licensed_Practical_Nurse rdf:type owl:Class ;
                          rdfs:subClassOf :Nurse .

:MastersDegree rdf:type owl:Class ;
               owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Degree
                                                          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                            owl:onProperty :hasEducationLevel ;
                                                            owl:hasValue :MastersEducationLevel
                                                          ]
                                                        ) ;
                                     rdf:type owl:Class
                                   ] .

:Mobile_Developer rdf:type owl:Class ;
                  rdfs:subClassOf :Software_Developer .

:Nurse rdf:type owl:Class ;
       rdfs:subClassOf :Nursing_Occupation .

:Nurse_Manager rdf:type owl:Class ;
               rdfs:subClassOf :Nursing_Occupation .

:Nursing rdf:type owl:Class ;
         rdfs:subClassOf :ProgramOfStudy .

:NursingDegree rdf:type owl:Class ;
               owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Degree
                                                          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                            owl:onProperty :programOfStudy ;
                                                            owl:someValuesFrom :Nursing
                                                          ]
                                                        ) ;
                                     rdf:type owl:Class
                                   ] .

:Nursing_Occupation rdf:type owl:Class ;
                    rdfs:subClassOf :Occupation .

:Occupation rdf:type owl:Class .

:ProgramOfStudy rdf:type owl:Class .

:Registered_Nurse rdf:type owl:Class ;
                  rdfs:subClassOf :Nurse .

:Software_Developer rdf:type owl:Class ;
                    rdfs:subClassOf :Occupation .

:Web_Developer rdf:type owl:Class ;
               rdfs:subClassOf :Software_Developer .

:BachelorsEducationLevel rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                                  :EducationLevel .

:MastersEducationLevel rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                                :EducationLevel .
```

I've considered using object properties and individuals, but I'm not sure how to achieve the generalization I'm looking for when specifying the value for an individual's object property.

Can someone make a suggestion on how I could model these degree to occupation pathways in OWL?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `Software developer` is the top of your hierarchy of compatible careers for CS degrees, then you'd assert something like

`Software developer` subClassOf exist hasDegree `CS degree`

To stop a `Nurse manager` from needing just a `Nursing degree` (I suspect they'd need a management course of some sort?) you can do something similar:

`Nurse manager` subClassOf exist hasDegree `Management role`

Now, an individual without that sort of degree will not be classified as a `Nurse manager` (potential). If you assert they're nurse managers, though, the system will not complain.